# Using python to simulate USB keyboard

Tags: python, usb, pyserial, hid, pyusb

I'm well aware of different automation libraries that I can use in conjunction with Python (or even as a separate program/entity all together)-- that's not what I need here...

***Here's what I'd like to accomplish...***

```
{COMP1}  -------->  {COMP2}

(1) --> = COMP1 USB port[01] is connected to COMP2 USB port[01]
    (it could be any port, I'm just using [01] as an example)
(2) COMP1 USB port[01] "looks-like" a Generic USB keyboard
    (I'll maybe need to spoof HID values so COMP2 treats it as a keyboard)
(3) My program would send keystroke signals into COMP2 in such a way that
    COMP2 would treat the input as any other connected keyboard device
```

I've looked a little bit into [pyusb](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) but I think it looks like that's taking control of the connected device, it's not emulating/simulating a device.  If I have that wrong, please point me to the right documentation so I understand how to issue signals as if I were a keyboard through the USB port

I think this [article](http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2012/07/emulating-usb-devices-with-python.html) begins to really scratch the surface but I have no clue what to do next with it.

Perhaps PySerial might be another method but I haven't found any solid examples where python is issuing keystrokes to the USB (it seems to be listening instead)

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: USB does not work that way

Answer (score 2):

I ended up **using a Teensy 3.2 device** instead of coding with python
Here's where you can research/purchase it https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/

Basically, this arduino-cousin **hardware can masquerade/imitate any USB device** (sending a certain HID number)...Once connected to another computer (and a tiny bit of coding), you can send a sequence of keystrokes/commands programmatically to the target computer-- it was very easy (sure soldering for the first time felt a bit *mad scientist*) but it was really fun too.

I'll post up the code samples on github if anyone is curious or responds to this thread in the future.